# Does it make sense to use Auth::attempt in APIs login by API token?

Tags: php, laravel

I see that it is a very common approach to see something like :

```
if (!Auth::attempt($request->only('email', 'password'))) {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Invalid login details'
            ], 401);
        }
```

Even if the Laravel app works only with JWT or other kinds of token based login (Sanctum tokens, for example).

But i was wondering, does it make sense? In my undestanding this method will try to execute a traditional web based login, what isn't what is trying to be archieved here. The method seems to be used only to verify if the attempt was true or false, but doesn't Laravel have a more appropriate and more focused method for this?

Answer (score 0):

##### Yes, it makes sense to implement. But have you looked at the security side?

While authentication through a email/password combination is considered generally secure, there are use cases where it isn't considered the best option or even safe.

Email/password authentication is simple to implement, but not the best way to protect an API. The client application has to keep the clear text password in memory to send it along with each request. Not safe enough.

##### The problem with a password is that they are reused

A password is a valuable target, because the same password is likely to be used on multiple services. So you exchange it for a shorter-lived access token, which, if stolen, presents less risk for your user. And you can't easily revoke a password - forcing users to change their passwords is a hassle. Revoking an access token is easy.

Comment: Where i said the login used only email and password? The question was referenced JWT and Sanctum token APIs.

Comment: Why need to login when you have got the token? Sanctum and OAuth (passport) have no login functionality. They make tokens.